# How to rectify file not found exception in Windows application?

Tags: c#

I am generating barcode in a Windows application using C#. I have written the code but here I am unable to generate the barcode. I am getting an error like

> file found not Exception  (pfc.AddFontFile(_c39FontFileName);

Please help me.

My code is like this:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
c39.FontFamilyName = "c:\\FREE3OF9.TTF";
c39.FontFileName = "Free 3 of 9";
int barSize = System.Convert.ToInt32(txtFontSize.Text);

c39.FontSize = barSize;
c39.ShowCodeString = true;
if (txtTitle.Text + "" != "")
    c39.Title = txtTitle.Text;
Bitmap objBitmap = c39.GenerateBarcode(txtrand.Text);
objBitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.png);

objBitmap.Save("c:\\image.png");
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this

```
c39.FontFamilyName = "c:\\FREE3OF9.TTF";
c39.FontFileName = "Free 3 of 9";
```

Should have been

```
c39.FontFamilyName = "Free 3 of 9";
c39.FontFileName = "c:\\FREE3OF9.TTF";
```